# Synching two ancestraly related Git repositories ignoring some commits

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, git-submodules

I have a number of git repositories which I would like to:

1. Port to a new git server.
2. Add submodules to them.

This on it's own would be straight forward, the thing is that I would like to do this progressively. That is, I want users to keep cloning/pulling/pushing to the old repos and at the same time port those commits to the new repos. Eventually that "old" server would be removed and users would start using the new one with the submodules. I have a jenkins server which would be in charge of porting all those repos from the old server to the new one everynight.
Again, that would be pretty straight forward except from the fact that I want the new repos to have some submodules which the old repos don't have. So the situation would be like:

```
Old Repo        New Repo
    |               |
 CommitA-------->CommitA
    |               |
    |            CommitB (Add submodules)
    |               |
 CommitC-------->CommitC
    |               |
 CommitD-------->CommitD
    |               |
    .               .
    .               .
    .               .
```

So as you can see I want to port all commits from the Old Repo to the new one whitout loosing any of their information (I don't want to just copy sources from the Old one and overwrite them in the New repo, as that would loose the comments and intermediate commits, since that porting operation would be performed once a day).

Can somebody give me some hints on how to achieve this and also how can I perform it in an "automated" mode (no just cherry picking one by one the commits).

Thanks!

**EDIT**

So I have been trying and right now I have:

```
#Clone "New Repo"
git clone ssh://<NewRepoServer>/bitbucket_tests bitbucket_tests
cd bitbucket_tests
#Add "Old Repo" remote
git remote add old_repo <OldRepoServer/bitbucket_tests>;
#update New Repo remote
git remote update origin;
#update Old Repo remote
git remote update old_repo;
#Loop through all branches, and try to merge them
for remote_branch in `git branch -r | grep old_repo | grep -v master | grep -v HEAD | awk '{gsub(/^[^\/]+\//,"",$1); print $1}'`; do 
    git branch -f --track $remote_branch
    git checkout $remote_branch
    git pull -s recursive -X patience -X theirs old_repo $remote_branch
    git pull
done
git checkout master
git pull -s recursive -X patience -X theirs old_repo master
git pull

#Push results to Old Repo
git push origin refs/remotes/old_repo/*:refs/heads/*;
```

While this works fine if there are not modifications to "New Repo" branches, it fails when NewRepo has some commit which does not exist in OldRepo (such as CommitB from the graph above):

```
git push origin 'refs/remotes/old_repo/*:refs/heads/*'
To ssh://<NewRepoServer>/bitbucket_tests
 ! [rejected]        old_repo/testBranch -> testBranch (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to                 'ssh://<NewRepoServer>/bitbucket_tests'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

How can I automatically merge those changes into the contents of OldRepo automatically without requiring user intervention?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand you right. I guess the easiest way to handle this, is to add another/new remote branch/branches to your new server and fetch & pull the changes. So you will have all of your commits and history.
For more information you can read https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I have run into problems when in comes to pulling all branches from the old remote and pushing them to the one. What if a new branch appears on the old remote? What sequence of commands would you actually recommend?

Comment: 1. Fetch and Pull all changes from your old remote branches to your local repository with 'git fetch --all' and 'git pull'
2. Add your new remote url and push your local branches to the new remote with 'git remote add newRemote URL' and with 'git remote -v' you can check if the URL to your new Remote is right. Then push your local branches to your new Remote